# easy infix in Lean

Tags: lean4

Starting from this example in `Lean`

```
import Mathlib.Analysis.SpecialFunctions.Log.Basic
import Mathlib.Tactic

variable (a b c d e : ℝ)
open Real

#check (le_refl : ∀ a, a ≤ a)
#check (le_trans : a ≤ b → b ≤ c → a ≤ c)
#check (lt_of_le_of_lt : a ≤ b → b < c → a < c)
#check (lt_of_lt_of_le : a < b → b ≤ c → a < c)
#check (lt_trans : a < b → b < c → a < c)

example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) : a < e := by
  have h₅ : a < c := lt_of_le_of_lt h₀ h₁
  have h₆ : c < e := lt_of_le_of_lt h₂ h₃
  exact lt_trans h₅ h₆
```

Is there an easy infix notation which could make this form of infix rewriting possible

```
example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) : a < e := 
  (h₀ `lt_of_le_of_lt`  h₁)  `lt_trans` (h₂ `lt_of_le_of_lt`  h₃)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to declare one single infix then this is fast and usable:

```
infix:20 "<$$>" => my_fancy_function
```

Also if the namespaces are right you can do `n.add m` which sort of looks like infixes already.

For the generic case you can do something like this:

```
notation x "[`" y "`]" z => y x z

axiom foo : Nat → Nat → Nat
#check fun x y => x [` foo `] y [` foo `] y
```

You can swap out the ``` [``] ``` for other symbols But a single ` is special so you probably shouldn't try to use that. (Also, it doesn't seem possible to escape a single backtick surrounded by two backticks on StackExchange to produce `` ` ``. Please don't look at my source code to figure out how I did it.) Macro programming gurus may have a more robust solution.

Comment: To piggyback on your comment about `n.add`, if you have the namespaces for that to work, then you can use `|>.add` for a truely infix operation, e.g. `(n - m) |>.add (m |>.add k)`.

Comment: nice, that's a lot of reasonable options to explore

Answer (score 2):

On the off chance that you are just interested in cleaner proofs in this specific case of transitivity of `<`, `≤` and combinations thereof (or similar transitive relations), you can use `calc` mode for a clean proof:

```
example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) : a < e := 
  calc
    a ≤ b := h₀
    _ < c := h₁
    _ ≤ d := h₂
    _ < e := h₃
```

It should be possible to also make calc mode work with your own custom relations if they have similar transitivity lemmas (although I don't know the details).

Comment: it's certainly a nice reminder

Answer (score 1):

A simple quick and dirty way is using the piping operators `|>` and `<|`.
Namely, `foo x y` can be written as `(x |> foo <| y)`:

```
example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) : a < e :=
  (h₀ |> lt_of_le_of_lt <| h₁)  |> lt_trans <| (h₂ |> lt_of_le_of_lt <| h₃)
```

Specifically, `x |> foo` says send the value of `x` to `foo`, so it is `foo x`.  And `foo x <| y` says send the value of `y` to `foo x`, so it is `foo x y`.  The normal reason for using `<|` is that it binds really loosely, so it lets you avoid using parentheses on the right expression.  In Lean 3 it was written with `$`.

Comment: oh nice !  also nice to see `|>` used in so many languages nowadays